# Актуальны ли джава сервлеты?

Tags: java

Насколько я знаю джава апплеты мёртвая технология, не относится ли это к сервелетам?

Comment: Нет, не относится.

Comment: Например `spring` полностью на сервлетах сделан, а он очень даже жив

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть надёжный способ проверить мертва ли та или иная java-технология - зайти в документацию и посмотреть, есть ли метка deprecated. На пакете java.applet и всех входящих в него классах [есть](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/applet/package-summary.html), а на javax.servlet [нет](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/package-summary.html). Наоборот, есть [обновление спецификации](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369) от сентября 2017-го года. Это почти со 100% надёжностью гарантирует, что в следующие 10 лет сервлеты никуда не денутся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]